# VScode change references keybinding

Tags: visual-studio-code

Referring to [VScode doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/keybindings) I can see that `⇧F12` finds references. Is it possible to select and rename all the references in one go? I am aware of `⇧⌘L` and `⌘K ⌘D` key combinations, but they're not exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`F2` is what you're looking for.

Quick tip: when you are not sure if a feature exists or not, press `F1` and start typing the action you'd like to do. In your case, `F1 + 'rena'` shows as result `Rename Symbol (F2)`.